# How to pass credentials for database to wcf service?

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, database-connection

We have a WCF service that connects to an oracle database.  The connection to the database must be done using the credentials of the user that is calling the service.

How can I set it up so that I can get access to the username and password set in the client credentials at the client so that I can add these to the connections string created when I want to connect to the database to get the data for the service call?

Or is there some other way that this should be handled?

If it makes a difference we will be using proxy identity in the oracle database, so all users will connect as a main user and the proxy identity will be set to be the passed credentials to ensure that the queries are executed in the context of the proxy user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup your service(s) to use [Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx). This way they will take on the identity of the service client.

Once this is setup, you can get the caller's Windows Identity like this:

```
WindowsIdentity callerWindowsIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
```

[Check out this blog post](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx) and see if it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks but we are not using windows indentity, we are using username/password authenitication

Comment: How are you authenticating callers? Are you using a customUserNamePasswordValidatorType?

Comment: currently we are not authenticating.  I should have said that we want to use username password authentication...  we are trying to investigate what our options are...

Comment: Well you can still use Windows authentication. Your client can pass username/password in the client credentials, and then you can specify a service behavior to map those credentials to a Windows account.
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MapToWindowsAccount">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

Comment: Formatting sucks on that, sorry...see the Impersonation link in my answer.

Comment: As for custom username/password authentication, here is a link to show you how to do it. This will not help you with your Oracle connection problem though, for that I think you're going to want to try to use Windows authentication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx

Comment: If I set username and password on the client how can I get access to what was set on the server?  I don't really want to validate the user, I just want to pass what the client set to my connection string and let the DB handle authentication...  Do I have to implement a custom username password validator, and store the given username and password info when my validate method gets called, then use those in the service method?  Where can I store them so they are accessible to the service method?

Comment: The short answer is I don't think you can without coming up with some way (read hack) of storing the password temporarily from your validator to your service operation. You best option is to use Windows authentication to talk to the Oracle database, and use impersonation so that your service is invoked as the caller's identity. I'll update my answer with some more sample code that might illustrate the problem.

Comment: I think I found an article that will help you out.

Comment: thanks, that post looks useful  I'll take a while to digest but meanwhile +1 for the effort.